# Print issue with bootstrap fixed navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, printing

I've made website with bootstrap fixed navbar. It has fixed navbar so in stylesheet body have top-padding of 70px.

When i print the page it add that extra space at top of paper. What can i do to remove that extra space causing by that top-padding.

Below is print preview with padding

[image: Print Preview of with padding]

Below is print preview without padding which i want with less space at top.

[image]

If i remove the padding the print is as i want but the in browser the content get behind the nav bar and i can't see the first 2-3 lines.

Please give me some solution to retain the fixed navbar and also the padding don't get include in print.

Comment: why don't you create a css only for printing?

Comment: I've created style sheet for print only and t worked, thanks for solution. I didn't know that we can also create style sheet only for printing.

Comment: Great you solved! Since it actually is the correct solution, can i move comment to answer? Ups, just saw someone put it as solution already. So i don't need to add it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add a new print stylesheet like so (place this after your main stylesheet):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/print.css" media="print">
```

In print.css set your new CSS rule for the body tag like so:

```
body {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

Comment: It worked, thanks for solution. I didn't know that we can also create style sheet only for printing.

Answer (score 10):

I know you may or may not *want* to show the navbar in print. I wanted to show it, so I added this in my CSS (Bootstrap 3):

```
@media print { 
    .navbar {
        display: block;
        border-width:0 !important;
    }
    .navbar-toggle {
        display:none;
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me, not the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer works perfectly, but if you don't want to add a new style sheet, an alternative is to wrap the body padding in a media tag.  In your Site.css:

```
@media screen {
body {
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

}

This specifies that the style should only be applied when viewing the page, not printing.